# Overlay for several moduls possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

Why can I not use the class myBtn for several overlays ? It is a class it must work or not? I want to use the overlay function for several buttons  is it in some way possible ? I know the ids can not been used for several times thats why I changes it to classes but it still does not work.

I have the example from w3schools below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
-webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #fefefe;
width: 100%;
-webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-name: slideIn;
animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: white;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0} 
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0} 
to {opacity: 1}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <h2>Modal Header</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
  <p>Some other text...</p>
 </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
 </div>
</div>

</div>

<h2>2 Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

 <!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <h2>Modal Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
  <p>Some other text...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
 </div>
 </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")[0];

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

U are using 2 times the following id.

```
id="myModal"
```

Change it to class and also the javascript part so it looks like this:

```
var modal = document.getElementByClassName('myModal');
```

As u said, u can only use once an id.

Comment: But it is working at least in one of them @A10? Or u also need help for making overlay work.

Comment: No the first one is working, but if I use it for another one it does not work. I also changed every id into a class but a second one or several different ones dont work.